# How to make "Page Slider" Jquery and WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

I'm looking to create a website that has a similar sliding navigation effect found here on Toyota's website.

http://www.toyota.com/4Runner/#!/Welcome

You'll notice the site's content slides up and down vertically depending on which navigation button is hit. I'm very proficient at WordPress and have a basic understanding of Jquery. Can anyone offer any suggestions on the concepts involved in doing this or point me to a good resource?

Thanks in advance!

Don

Answer (score 0):

You can try `black label` theme for your wordpress.

http://themeforest.net/item/black-label-fullscreen-video-image-background/336949

Comment: Hi Ashish, thanks for the reply. I'm on the site but didn't see the specific affect I was looking for. Can you provide any additional guidance for where to look on the site? Thanks

Comment: there are thousands of wordpress themes in the market. you can search the one you wants

Comment: As I  mentioned in my original post, I'm looking for a specific effect that's created in Jquery and not just any standard theme. It's basically a vertical content sliding effect that I've seen on site's like http://www.toyota.com/4Runner/#!/Welcome. If you know of any tutorials or even themes that have this effect, that'd be great.